# Docker can't start because docker container with id exists?

Tags: docker

My docker container can't restart after I upgrade the docker to Docker version 17.06.2-ce. The error message and my compose file are following:

```
Starting wordpress ... error
Starting mysql     ... error

ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: oci runtime error: container with id exists: 
b3951fd8b599c273f39d3b29085d525828a92dabe518f42860ba6535d5edad6e


ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: oci runtime error: container with id exists: be9c3682bb66720c8015cfe9e9025c68a917204444e9b77f68b63d84f0469b71


======================
```

the docker compose file  is:

```
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xxx

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
```

I have reboot the instance but not working.
Need your help!

Comment: Finaily, I copy the data from the old container and start a new one, then paste the data to the new container. The old one can't start again.

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried to remove the stopped containers from your docker engine?

You can show all container with `docker ps -a`. This will give you a list of the local containers (stopped and running). Identify the old wordpress and mysql containers and remove them with `docker rm <container-id>`. After removing the old containers you should be able to run your docker compose file again.

Comment: In that case you can also try `docker-compose rm -v` and/or `docker system prune -f`

Comment: OK, it works, but I want that container, `rm` is a destructive command for my situation. my SQL server databases is in the container

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo, if you store data inside a container you are using containers the wrong way! You should probably open a separate question for your problem, to get specific answers...

Comment: " if you store data inside a container you are using containers the wrong way!" good to know. That's how I've been doing my jupyter containers... but I guess what your saying is I should be storing my data outside of it.  However... I do often install modules...

Comment: @thistleknot you should ask a separate question to get a detailed answer. If you need additional modules you should create your own Dockerfile that extends from the original one. This way you can get an image with all modules installed. To store data either use docker-volumes or mount the host filesystem to your container using a bind mount volume.

Answer (score 18):

This is because the system was restarted abnormally and the container was left in a bad state.  To find the state information:

`find -name "b3951fd8b599c273f39d3b29085d525828a92dabe518f42860ba6535d5edad6e"`

That should result in something like:

`/run/docker/runtime-runc/moby/b3951fd8b599c273f39d3b29085d525828a92dabe518f42860ba6535d5edad6e`

You can remove the state information with:

`sudo rm -rf /run/docker/runtime-runc/moby/b3951fd8b599c273f39d3b29085d525828a92dabe518f42860ba6535d5edad6e/`

Then start the container fresh with:

`docker start b395`

Then you should be up and running.

Comment: didn't work for me. removed the `state.json` and then the directory, but there are still references in `/sys/fs/cgroup/` which I can't remove (there's an unkillable zombie process of the last docker container which i simply try to ignore)

Comment: Very nice! Deleted all in moby folder and old container works

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes I face the same error when I update the Docker version. You can stop (`docker-compose down`) and then start the container again. I think it is due to some runtime conflicts when adapting to the newer version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a [documented bug](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/49) for that specific version upgrade. The fix would be at https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/pull/117/files.

I haven't found the proper way to upgrade to 17.06+ under my environment, but you can get your containers running again. Try this:

- See if you can downgrade to 17.03.
- Start the containers again under that version. The first time it might fail, **but starting them a second time might just work** if your environment is like mine. For instance:

`$ docker start wp
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container with id exists: dc9c6a17c102747d81fbad674e93257a5b31f15e0837ed64b39c63eda5e6f46a
Error: failed to start containers: wp
$ docker start wp
wp
$ docker ps | grep wp
dc9c6a17c102        wordpress           "docker-entrypoint..."   2 months ago        Up 2 minutes       80/tcp     wp`

I've written about that on the [Gentoo Forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8141660.html#8141660) (for my case) and on [Github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33688#issuecomment-344472081).